# Unable to replace the tags of UIButton(s)

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uibutton

I have say for example 7 `UIButtons` namely c1 to c7. Now I have assigned tags starting from 1 to 7 respectively for the `UIButtons` c1 to c7.

Now when I select c2 for example it is removed from `superView` so now the tag for c2 which was 2 is transferred to c3 , 3 to c4 and so on.

This is what I have tried but logic is not working properly. I have posted question with similar concern before but didn't get any proper response.

```
-(void)totesttheFunction
{
    for(int i=0; i<7; i++)
    {
        UIButton *testHere = (UIButton*)[self.view viewWithTag:i];
        if([testHere isSelected])
        {
            int backuptagFor = testHere.tag;
            CGFloat diff = 30.0;
            for(int j=i+1; j<7;j++)
            {
                UIButton *btnToReplace = (UIButton*)[self.view viewWithTag:j];
                 CGRect setRect = CGRectMake(btnToReplace.frame.origin.x-diff, btnToReplace.frame.origin.y, btnToReplace.frame.size.width, btnToReplace.frame.size.height);
                btnToReplace.tag = backuptagFor;
                [testHere removeFromSuperview];

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Do not use tags. Keep pointers to the buttons in a mutable array and use the indexes into the array. When you delete a button from the interface remove it from the array. All the indexes will automatically adjust exactly as you describe.

Comment: @matt can you help me out how to implement it

Comment: @Ramshad iam checking it

Comment: @Ramshad how will i replace this in the array

Comment: @Anoop Vaidya http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15018637/replace-move-objects-in-nsmutablearray . i have a question almost similar to the one you have answered can you help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    for(int itemIndex = 1; itemIndex <= 7; itemIndex++)
    {
        UIButton *btn = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(itemIndex*40, 10, 30, 30)];
        btn.tag = itemIndex;
        [self.view addSubview:btn];

        if (itemIndex == 3 ||itemIndex == 4)
        {
            [btn setSelected:YES];
        }
    }

    [self testFunction];
}


- (void)testFunction
{
    int totalButtons = 7;
    int totalRemovedButtons = 0;

    for(int itemIndex = 1; itemIndex <= totalButtons; itemIndex++)
    {
        UIButton *testHere = ([[self.view viewWithTag:itemIndex] isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]])?(UIButton *)[self.view viewWithTag:itemIndex]:nil;
        if([testHere isSelected])
        {
            [testHere removeFromSuperview];
            NSLog(@"removed button with tag:%d",itemIndex + totalRemovedButtons);

            for (int tempItemIndx = itemIndex + 1; tempItemIndx <= totalButtons; tempItemIndx++)
            {
                 UIButton *nextButton = ([[self.view viewWithTag:tempItemIndx] isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]])?(UIButton *)[self.view viewWithTag:tempItemIndx]:nil;
                nextButton.tag = tempItemIndx - 1;
            }

           itemIndex--;
           totalRemovedButtons ++;
        }

        NSLog(@"loop run %d",itemIndex);
    }

    NSLog(@"-------------------------------------------------------------------");

    //Checking the updated tags.

    for(int itemIndex = 1; itemIndex <= (totalButtons - totalRemovedButtons); itemIndex++)
    {
        UIButton *testHere = ([[self.view viewWithTag:itemIndex] isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]])?(UIButton *)[self.view viewWithTag:itemIndex]:nil;
        NSLog(@"New tags %d",testHere.tag);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
 loop run 1
 loop run 2
 removed button with tag:3
 loop run 2
 removed button with tag:4
 loop run 2
 loop run 3
 loop run 4
 loop run 5
 loop run 6
 loop run 7
 ---------------------
 New tags 1
 New tags 2
 New tags 3
 New tags 4
 New tags 5
```

Comment: @NSS: not at all.. if he is removing a button from superview, we are getting the next button using "itemIndex + 1" and re-assigned the tag as current index. So the next iteration will skip the next button becuase its tags assiged as itemIndex. So we have to decrement the loop itemIndex only if removed a button. It should not run as infinite.

Comment: so u mean itemIndex+1 will assign increased value to itemIndex? means currently itemIndex =3, then itemIndex will get value 4 only by doing itemIndex+1?? U r not assigning that increased value to itemIndex!!!

Comment: @Ramshad not getting the output what i expected

Comment: @user2963228 : just try it by omitting line itemIndex-- in the above code.

Comment: @NSS: "itemIndex + 1" will get the next button.. if the "itemIndex" is 3, and it is selected, we should remove this from view. then we will use "itemIndex + 1" to get next button/4th button and we will assign its tag as 3 (itemIndex)..

Comment: @NSS: next,itemIndex--; is wrote for handling the removal of next button. what happen if the reassigned tag button is selected? this issue will only happen when he is looping all buttons instead of target action.

Comment: @Ramshad but code is not working the way it is expected to..when i nslogged the tags still displaying same old tags..and in betwen 1 tag is 0.. no idea what is happening

Comment: @user2963228 : that's what I am telling.. it goes to infinite loop!! this can't be desired answer.

Comment: @Ramshad infinite loop :(

Comment: if possible, please send your source code to shamsutk87@gmail.com

Comment: @user2963228: if possible, please paste the log as per the updated answer.

Comment: @Ramshad i tried out the edited code. now no infinite loop but here the only the very next btn to the selected btn getting replaced tag..

Comment: @user2963228: please check the updated answer..I have done a test run and u can see the logs too..

Comment: @Ramshad yeah i will try

Comment: @NSS from the updated answer, you can understand the importance of "itemIndex--;"..  if the selected button tags are not sequential, it deosn't create any issues. If the selected button tags are sequential, you have to decrement the index.Otherwise it doesn't remove the next button from the view, if it is selected. Also, you can see from the log that, it doesn't cause any infinite loop...

Comment: @Ramshad can you plz up vote..someone has down voted .. i asked a genuine question..got the solution now..what is there to downvote

Comment: these uibuttons are added into an array too..so when selected btns are removed how wud i make changes to the array .

Comment: @NSS iam also adding these uibuutons to array..so wen the selected btns are removed it should the corresponding objectatindex should also be either removed or replaced

Answer (score 1):

Apply below approach first **delete old UI** and **re-generate new UI from scratch assign them same tags again**

e.g. 123456 - No 4 deleted - 12356 - store remaining data - re-generate new UI from old data
now 12345

```
- (IBAction)actionDeletePrevEmp:(UIButton *)sender
{

// ********* DELETED OLD UI AND GENERATED DATA FROM OLD UI **********

NSMutableArray *tempArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

for (int BTNCounter = 1; BTNCounter < 8 ;BTNCounter++)
{
    if (BTNCounter == sender.tag)
    { // do not add contents to array
      // delete it from UI

        [(UIButton *)[self.view viewWithTag:BTNCounter]removeFromSuperview];

        continue;
    }


}


// ************* GENERATING NEW UI WITH TEMP DATA **************


int empSizeCounter = 50;

for (int loopCounter = 0, BTNTagCounter = 1 ; BTNTagCounter < 7; loopCounter++)
{
    viewPreviousEmployerList = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, empSizeCounter, 320.0, 50.0)];


    //  viewPreviousEmployerList.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];

    deletePrevEmpButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeSystem];
    //[deletePrevEmpButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"checkbox.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    deletePrevEmpButton = [[UIButton alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(264.0, 10.0, 30.0, 30.0)];
    deletePrevEmpButton.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];
    deletePrevEmpButton.titleLabel.text = @"X";
    deletePrevEmpButton.tag = BTNTagCounter;


    if (loopCounter+1 > [tempArray count])
    {
         btnTemp.text = @"";

                }
    else
    {
        btnTemp.text = tempArray[loopCounter];


    }




    BTNTagCounter++;
    [viewPreviousEmployerList addSubview:btnTemp];

    [self.viewAddEmployer addSubview:viewPreviousEmployerList];

    empSizeCounter = empSizeCounter + 50;


}
```

Comment: wth is this?? give specific ans..!

Comment: @NSS - I have come up with the same solution when i need to work  with TextFields - all textfields needs to be replaced by buttons

Comment: @bhavyakothari - just put code related to OP"s question otherwise he/she may be confuse when read your answer. Thanks :)

Comment: @bhavya : that I can understand from ur code.. but the thing is, if all he has to do replacing and all, then he can learn by tutorials..! better we should keep him on correct path rather than doing replacement n all.. may be there are chances that he get more confused or away from his desired solution while doing replacement!!! Jay Jinendra!

Answer (score 0):

First you need to add all button in NSMutableArray and follow me, (here array name is **_myArrayOfBtn**)
Add button's method such like, *(and make sure that each button's have same method name)*

```
[myBuutonName addTarget:self action:@selector(totesttheFunction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

And method declaration is like,

```
-(void) totesttheFunction:(UIButton *)sender
{
    [sender removeFromSuperview]; // just put this code.
    [_myArrayOfBtn removeObjectAtIndex:sender.tag];
    // replace tag of buttons
    for(int i = 1; i < _myArrayOfBtn.count; i ++)
    {
      UIButton *btn = (UIButton *)[_myArrayOfBtn objectAtIndex:i]
      btn.tag = i;
    }

}
```

Comment: @user2963228 - is it helpful for you ??

Comment: @iPatel : hold ur horses.. if it helped him, he will upvote and accept ur ans. Don't know about upvote, but hopefully will accept it. So be patient..! LOL

Comment: At least leave comment for where it is wrong in the code?